# post update doesn't work

Tags: git, git-pull

I can't do use git post-update hook to pull into my website folder, from the repo. I have two users, user1 and user2, who both belong to group admin_group (I verify

```
id user1 
uid=1001(user1) gid=1003(admin_group) groups=1003(admin_group),1001(user1)
```

Same for user2. I [looked up this](http://mapopa.blogspot.com/2009/10/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding.html) and performed these commands as my root:

```
cd repository.git
sudo chmod -R g+ws *
sudo chgrp -R admin_group *
git repo-config core.sharedRepository true
```

This above step was probably unnecessary, since I can push just fine. I also did:

```
cd websitedir
sudo chmod -R g+ws *
sudo chgrp -R admin_group *
```

However, my post-update hook still won't pull the files to the `websitedir` automatically.

```
// post-update
cd /var/www
env -i git pull
```

It must be running as a different user, but I don't know which one. How do I give the user running the post-update hook permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the post-update hook has the execute bit set.
2. It's unclear from your description if "websitedir" and "/var/www" are the same thing -- if your hook cds to "/var/www" and it's not a git repo, "git pull" isn't going to do anything.
3. Who owns "repository.git?"